# ENCRYPTION DECRYPTION IN SQL with C#.NET

Tags: c#, sql, encryption

I have created a Login page for my ASP.NET website project.

Now, all I need to do is:

1. Get the password string (that can be done easily.)
2. Encrypt the password via C# coding (need help with that)
3. Send the encrypted one to the SQL Server database.. (that can be done easily)
4. Decrypt the encrypted password in SQL, with the same encryption scheme used in C# code (need help with that)
5. and the last step, compare the password string (that also can be done easily)

I have used encryption only in C# Code.

I have also used encryption in SQL but separately, same as for C#.

The problem where I'm stuck is: I couldn't find a solution to encrypt the password in C#, and then use the same scheme to decrypt the password but in SQL.

Thanks, if anyone of you could help. :)

Comment: That is not at all how passwords should work. You don't encrypt them, you hash them, so they can't be reversed back to passwords. I also don't see why you should decrypt in SQL, you can do that from code as well. Reconsider your design.

Comment: why u are encrypting password in c# and sql both??? is it needed? u can encrypt the password in sql i mean u can save the encrypted password in sql and when u want that back u can decrypt  it and take that. if it is necessary to encrypt password in c# then u can use your own encryption algorithms i think it is more simple

Comment: @CodeCaster raises valid points.  Based on what you are asking I assume you are storing passwords in plain text? Really bad idea.

Comment: For example my application when sends the password on the network it gets filtered by the network, so i dont want it to be seen, as a consequence the encrypted one will travel to the database? can it be done?

Comment: all i need is security constraint to my project, tell me if there are any other alternatives or possiblities?

Comment: @DheerajSharma .U can create your own encryption algorithm in c#. and pass the encrypted data through network .and also the time u check the data u take the data from database and decrypt it using the same logic and check with the password that are entered by user.

Comment: @DheerajSharma if you want security constraint to your project then do not decrypt password once it is stored in the DB. You need to compare the input password(from user) to the already stored password, this will ensure safety to the sensitive data.

Comment: @DheerajSharma Try this link which match your job perfectly http://sqlblog.com/blogs/michael_coles/archive/2010/01/29/encrypt-it-in-net-decrypt-it-on-sql-server.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not just encrypt password, you should store hashed password in the SQL DB.
For more details on how to Hashed password refer this 
[How to securly hash password](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords)

For C# code to hash password you can refer this 
[How to Hash passwords in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa545602(v=cs.70).aspx)